# Get JSON value from remoteMessage Received onMessageReceived method [FCM] Push Notification

Tags: android, json, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

How do I get the value `image_id` on json object `payload` in json object `data` that I got from `remoteMessage` contained in `onMessageReceived` Method?

**MyFirebaseMessagingService.java**

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
public static final String TAG = "FirebaseMessageService";
Bitmap bitmapSmall;
Bitmap bitmapLarge;
Bitmap bitmapPush;
private JSONObject jsonObject;
private String strJSONValue = "{\"Data\":{\"judul_push\":\"pesan_push\" ,\"image_push\":\"icon_kecil\",\"icon_besar\":" +
                                "\"icon_kecil\",\"is_background\":\"tipe_push\",\"timestamp"
        +"\"payload\":{\"IMAGE_ID\":\"IMAGE_TYPE\" },{\"IMAGE_NAME\":\"IMAGE_PATH\"},{\"IMAGE_SEQUENCE\":\"AKTIF\"},{\"posted_by\":\"posted_date\"}}";
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "======== Message data payload======: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        }
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "======= Message Notification Body======: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }
        String title = remoteMessage.getData().get("judul_push");
        String message = remoteMessage.getData().get("pesan_push");
        String imageUriPush = remoteMessage.getData().get("image_push");
        String imageUriSmall = remoteMessage.getData().get("icon_kecil");
        String imageUriLarge = remoteMessage.getData().get("icon_besar");
        String background = remoteMessage.getData().get("is_background");
        String type = remoteMessage.getData().get("tipe_push");
        String time = remoteMessage.getData().get("timestamp");
        String datas = remoteMessage.getData().get("payload");
        String imid = remoteMessage.getData().get("IMAGE_ID");
try {
            final int numberOfItemsInResp = mJsonArrayPayload.length();
          for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItemsInResp; i++) {
                JSONObject mJsonObjectPayload = mJsonArrayPayload.getJSONObject(i);
                String image_id = mJsonObjectPayload.getString("IMAGE_ID");
                Config.abc1 = image_id;
                String image_type = mJsonObjectPayload.getString("IMAGE_TYPE");
                Config.abc2 = image_type;
                String image_name = mJsonObjectPayload.getString("IMAGE_NAME");
                Config.abc2 = image_name;
                String image_path = mJsonObjectPayload.getString("IMAGE_PATH");
                Config.abc3 = image_path;
                String image_sequence = mJsonObjectPayload.getString("IMAGE_SEQUENCE");
                Config.abc4 = image_sequence;
                String aktif = mJsonObjectPayload.getString("AKTIF");
                Config.abc5 = aktif;
                String posted_by = mJsonObjectPayload.getString("posted_by");
                Config.abc6 = posted_by;
                String posted_date = mJsonObjectPayload.getString("posted_date");
                Config.abc7 = posted_date;
            }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("MYAPP", "unexpected JSON exception HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!", e);
    }Log.i("PVL", "==============++LOG TYPE PUSH++======= " +Config.abc1);
        Log.i("PVL", "==============++LOG IMAGE NAME++======= " +Config.abc2);
        Log.i("PVL", "==============++LOG IMAGE PATH++======= " +Config.abc3);
        Log.i("PVL", "==============++LOG IMAGE SEQUENCE++======= " +Config.abc4);
        Log.i("PVL", "==============++LOG AKTIF++======= " +Config.abc5);
        Log.i("PVL", "==============++LOG POST BY++======= " +Config.abc6);
        Log.i("PVL", "==============++LOG POST DATE++======= " +Config.abc7);
        Log.i("PVL", "==============++LOG IMID++======= " +imid);
        bitmapSmall = getBitmapfromUrlSmall(imageUriSmall);
        Log.i("PVL", "==============++LOG BITMAP BITMALSMALL++======= " +bitmapSmall);
        bitmapLarge = getBitmapfromUrlLarge(imageUriLarge);
        Log.i("PVL", "==============++LOG BITMAP GETBITMAP++======= " +bitmapLarge);
        bitmapPush = getBitmapfromUrlPush(imageUriPush);
        Log.i("PVL", "==============++LOG BITMAP GETBITMAP PUSH++======= " +bitmapPush);
        Log.i("PVL", "==============++LOG IS BACKGROUND++======= " +background);
        Log.i("PVL", "==============++LOG TYPE PUSH++======= " +type);
        Log.i("PVL", "==============++LOG TIMESTAMP++======= " +time);
        sendNotification(message, title, bitmapSmall, bitmapLarge, bitmapPush, imageUriPush);
    }public void sendNotification(String messageBody, String title, Bitmap imageSmall, Bitmap imageLarge,Bitmap imagePush, String imageUriPush) {
        NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle s = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            try {
                s.bigLargeIcon(imageLarge);
                s.bigPicture(Picasso.with(context).load(imageUriPush).get());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            notificationBuilder.setStyle(s);
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.firebase_icon)
                    .setLargeIcon(imageLarge);
        } else {
            notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.firebase_icon);
        }
        NotificationManager notificationManager =(NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        int notifID =(int)System.currentTimeMillis();
        notificationManager.notify(notifID /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }public Bitmap getBitmapfromUrlSmall(String imageUrlSmall) {
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "======Log Image Bitmap: " +imageUrlSmall );
            URL url = new URL(imageUrlSmall);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap bitmapSmall = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return bitmapSmall;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.d(TAG, "+++++LOG IMAGE ++++" +e.getMessage() );
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
    public Bitmap getBitmapfromUrlLarge(String imageUrlLarge) {
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "======Log Image Bitmap: " +imageUrlLarge );
            URL url = new URL(imageUrlLarge);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap bitmapLarge = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return bitmapLarge;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.d(TAG, "+++++LOG IMAGE ++++" +e.getMessage() );
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
    public Bitmap getBitmapfromUrlPush(String imageUrlPush) {
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "======Log Image Push Bitmap: " +imageUrlPush );
            URL url = new URL(imageUrlPush);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap bitmapPush = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return bitmapPush;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "+++++LOG IMAGE PUSH++++" +e.getMessage() );
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

here is the json that I'm trying to parse.

```
{ "data": {
"judul_push":"jdl",
"pesan_push":"Isi",
"image_push": "xxx.png",
"icon_kecil": "xxx.png",
"icon_besar": "xxx.png",
"is_background":true,
"tipe_push":1,
"timestamp":"27-10-2016 22:51:48",
  "payload":{
        "IMAGE_ID":"1",
        "IMAGE_TYPE":"5",
        "IMAGE_NAME":"SPLASH SCREEN",
        "IMAGE_PATH":"xxx.png"
    }
},
  "to" : "fK2iL7Ptp9I:APA91bEFxlLyEIpr-vO2Fw3VoTOY6t-38EV_Thnn_SddL17nu7E1VcjZVEgpOAE7vEKn83Cxz3q9rXAapUq-00opHbuOrcw7AwPtFtyYAFb674olwttVLuQgCIByN-i_gJJy8z6rjUi7"
}
```

Here is my logcat error when Im trying to parse JSON object `payload`.

```
org.json.JSONException: Expected ':' after timestamp at character 128 of {"Data":{"judul_push":"pesan_push" ,"image_push":"icon_kecil","icon_besar":"icon_kecil","is_background":"tipe_push","timestamp"payload":{"IMAGE_ID":"IMAGE_TYPE" },{"IMAGE_NAME":"IMAGE_PATH"},{"IMAGE_SEQUENCE":"AKTIF"},{"posted_by":"posted_date"}}
         at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:450)
         at org.json.JSONTokener.readObject(JSONTokener.java:379)
         at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:100)
         at org.json.JSONTokener.readObject(JSONTokener.java:385)
         at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:100)
         at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:92)
         at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:108)
         at com.mitracomm.testingpush.MyFirebaseMessagingService.onMessageReceived(MyFirebaseMessagingService.java:100)
         at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzo(Unknown Source)
         at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzn(Unknown Source)
         at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzm(Unknown Source)
         at com.google.firebase.iid.zzb$2.run(Unknown Source)
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: that error output seems to be for the `strJSONValue` value. What does that do ?

Comment: I dont know what must I do. when Im trying parsing JSON object payload then the logcat show me like this I/PVL: ==============++LOG PAYLOAD++======= {"IMAGE_TYPE":"5","AKTIF":"Y","IMAGE_PATH":"xxx.png","IMAGE_SEQUENCE":"1","IMAGE_NAME":"SPLASH SCREEN,"IMAGE_ID":"1","posted_by":"Agus Awaludin","posted_date":"27-10-2016 22:51:48"}

Comment: That log output has nothing to do with the question, but that log is not an issue. Looks OK. The part of code producing the error seems to be missing from the question. Can you check if you are sending/posting `strJSONValue` and provide that code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

The answer is, first, if the Firebase send us JSON data and any JSON object included, we need to parse JSON data to string and then we need to convert the string value of JSON object (payload) to data type JSON object. And finally, we can get the string value (image_id) in JSON object (payload).

Comment: i received JSON empty...what could be the problem??

Answer (score 0):

Has a similar issue, I removed the JSON data from where it was complaining about the character, then re-typed it by hand. Somehow I had a hidden character. Hope this helps.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post; instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)